# Why can't my class be found, when it's in the same namespace?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

I have created a `modules` folder in my Laravel app. There are two modules so far, but I'm just concentrating on `core` here.

[image: folder structure]

I'm using Confide and Entrust to build User functionality, like so:

```
namespace App\Modules\Core;

use Zizaco\Confide\ConfideUser;
use Zizaco\Entrust\HasRole;

class User extends ConfideUser {
  use HasRole;
}
```

and Permissions:

```
namespace App\Modules\Core;

use Zizaco\Entrust\EntrustPermission;

class Permission extends EntrustPermission
{
}
```

and Roles:

```
namespace App\Modules\Core;

use Zizaco\Entrust\EntrustRole;

class Role extends EntrustRole
{
}
```

My Composer.json autoload reads:

```
"autoload": {
  "classmap": [
    "app/commands",
    "app/controllers",
    "app/models",
    "app/database/migrations",
    "app/database/seeds",
    "app/tests/TestCase.php",
    "app/modules"
  ],
  "psr-0": {
    "App\\Modules\\": "modules/"
  }
},
```

I put the psr-0 stuff in there because I couldn't get things to work. They still don't work, though the output autoload files when I run composer seem to have promising entries in them.

The database has been migrated, and now I'm trying to run the database seeding. My seeding script reads:

```
use App\Modules\Core\User;
use App\Modules\Core\Role;
use App\Modules\Core\Permission;

class UserTablesSeeder extends Seeder {

  public function run()
  {
    DB::table('users')->insert(array(
      'email'  => 'xxx',
      'first_name'  => 'xxx',
      'password'  => 'xxxx',
      'active'  => 1
    ));

    $admin = new Role;
    $admin->name = 'Admin';
    $admin->save();

    $manageUsers = new Permission;
    $manageUsers->name = 'manage_standard_users';
    $manageUsers->display_name = 'Manage Users';
    $manageUsers->save();

    $admin->perms()->sync(array($manageUsers->id));

    $user = User::where('email','=','xxx')->first();
    $user->attachRole($admin);
  }
}
```

But when I run `php artisan db:seed` I get an error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Permission' not found in /home/wedding/quincy/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php on line 604
{"error":{"type":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException","message":"Class 'Permission' not found","file":"\/home\/wedding\/quincy\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Database\/Eloquent\/Model.php","line":604}}
```

If I get rid of all the namespacing it all works just fine, but I think I should keep the namespaces because of the modularity I'm trying to create.

I've run `composer dump-autoload`, and `install` for when I added the psr-0 entry. So I'm not sure what else I need to do. I'm very new to composer, so at this point I'm lost as to what the problem is.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: PSR-0 maps namespace to directory location, which you might be "breaking" my by setting "App\Modules" namespace to the one directory "modules". I haven't tested that theory. You may also need to capitalize your directory names to match the namespaces. Again, I haven't read psr-0 that thoroughly to know - that might be a *nix vs Windows things more than a PSR-0 issue.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if you found your answer.

I think you need to update your role and permission namespaced class names here:

File: vendor/entrust/config/config.php:

(Default is just "Role" and "Permission" without a namespace, so it doesn't work when you move your implementations into one).

You also have two other options:

- add an alias for the fully namedspaced permission and role class on the app/config.php (Role => "Namespace").
- there's a mechanism to override package config settings with appropriately named files. You can override just the two entries you need (the Role and Permission namespaces).

Answer (score 1):

Confide and Entrust both are looking for Role and Permission model in global namespace. As you have changed namespace of both these models, Confide and Entrust are not able to find it. To solve this problem, you need to override Entrust configuration.

- Create directory "app/config/packages/zizaco/entrust"
- Copy file "vendor/zizaco/entrust/src/config/config.php" to "app/config/packages/zizaco/entrust/config.php"
- Edit "app/config/packages/zizaco/entrust/config.php" and change following two lines
  'role' => 'App\Modules\Core\Role',
  'permission' => 'App\Modules\Core\Permission',
- php artisan clear-compiled
- php artisan optimize

Answer (score 0):

You should rely on Laravel's packages (created thru Workbench, for instance) while developing localy.
Packages are the primary way of adding functionality to Laravel.

Workbench packages and their classes are handled automaticaly by Laravel - no need to configure anything.

More informations here: http://laravel.com/docs/packages

Comment: My app isn't dependent on these modules, it IS these modules. That's why I thought the workbench wasn't the place for them. I'm merely trying to break the app itself into more manageable pieces, and I should be able to structure that how I like. That said, if I can't get it to work, I may be using the workbench, yes. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: So I decided to move the whole thing to a package to see if that works, and I get exactly the same error message.

PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Permission' not found in /home/wedding/quincy/workbench/pioneer/quincy-core/vendor/illuminate/database/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php on line 604
{"error":{"type":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException","message":"Class 'Permission' not found","file":"\/home\/wedding\/quincy\/workbench\/pioneer\/quincy-core\/vendor\/illuminate\/database\/Illuminate\/Database\/Eloquent\/Model.php","line":604}}

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use your own modules instead of standard workbench packages, check out this article that depics how to achieve that:

http://creolab.hr/2013/05/modules-in-laravel-4/

summary by the author ( [Boris Strahija](http://creolab.hr/) ):

Laravel 4 is heavily based on composer packages, which is a good thing, but sometimes developers (like myself) like to separate their code into modules. This is especially nice when building larger projects. Now this was fairly easy to do in Laravel 3 with the bundles system, but in Laravel 4 many people just recommend building packages since L4 has a nice workbench feature. This is all good, but sometimes I like to separate my app specific controllers and views into modules, and not have to go through it with the workbench.

In short, you have to

- put your modules code somwhere (for example /app/modules/)
- include the directory in composer.json file, under autoload/classmap
- create an appropriate service providers (Laravel 4 uses service providers to register and boot up the packages, you can use it with modules as well)
- register the service providers - add them to app config in  “app/config/app.php” under the providers array

So now we have out modules fully working. You can add module specific routes, group your controllers/views/models, get module configuration like this:

```
Config::get('content::channels');
```

Or get translated phrases like this:

```
Lang::get('shop::errors.no_items_in_cart');
```

Finally, to test your modules you can create some routes, but that is up to you how you use your code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is, in fact, the tutorial I was following. I think it may actually be a problem with Entrust.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at Doctrine composer.json, for example `/vendor/doctrine/cache/composer.json`:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": { "Doctrine\\Common\\Cache\\": "lib/" }
},
```

The files are located in:

```
/vendor/doctrine/cache/lib/Doctrine/Common/Cache/ArrayCache.php
/vendor/doctrine/cache/lib/Doctrine/Common/Cache/Cache.php
... and so on
```

By that logic, I think you should put your files in:

```
modules/App/Modules/Core/User.php
modules/App/Modules/Core/Permission.php
modules/App/Modules/Core/Role.php
```

Answer (score 0):

From you screenshot the Permission class is located in the `models` folder so when you include your namespace you should type

```
use App\Modules\Core\Models\Permission;
```